# Pegar ancora url com PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso pegar os dados de uma âncora na url, segue link:

http://192.168.110.4/jornal/1-jornal1#8

Necessito dessa `ID 8` que está na âncora, o problema é que não posso utilizar Javascript para pegá-la.

Necessito utilizar somente PHP.

Estou utilizando Codeigniter, porém, se eu utilizar `$this->uri->segment()`, ele não reconhece a âncora como um segmento.

Comment: O PHP não vai pegar essa informação mesmo. Essa informação é específica para o browser até onde eu sabia. Se quiser algo para o PHP, porque não usa um `GET`? Se for o caso, você também poderá usar o AJAX

Comment: Isso só é possível com JavaScript, ou com Javascript + PHP, pois o PHP é server side, ou seja, ele só captura informações que são processadas no lado servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é possível. Como esse valor nunca é enviado para o servido, o mesmo  não estará disponível em `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ou variáveis ​​predefinidas semelhantes.

Você precisaria de algum tipo de "mágica" no lado do cliente (por exemplo, usando Javascript), para passar esse valor par ao PHP.

A resposta original foi tirada do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317523/3096922)

Uma das soluções possíveis seria utilizando `Ajax` ou passando o valor desejado para um parâmetro da url também.

Deixando sua url com algo parecido com isso:

```
http://192.168.110.4/jornal/1-jornal1?id=5#8
```

Por que não? Assim você atenderia Javascript e PHP.

Answer (score -2):

Segundo me parece, cada segmento está divido por '/', portanto é normal que ele não reconheça o '#' como um delimitador de segmento.

O seguinte deverá funcionar. Primeiro extrair o segmento e depois isolar o id que voçê deseja.

```
$segment = $this->uri->segment(2); //obter o segmento
preg_match("/#([0-9]*)/", $segment, $matches); //isolar o id
$id = !empty($matches[1]) ? (int) $matches[1] : null; // verificar se este existe
```